# Binary Search Tree not working properly? (parse errors)

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, parse-error

I'm getting parse errors in my code. I'm probably missing something silly.. but after staring at it, I can't figure out what's wrong. The errors start at line 26:

BinaryTree.cpp:26: parse error before 'new
BinaryTree.cpp:31: parse error before ';'

....etc etc... any ideas?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class BinaryTree{

struct node{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
  }; 

  node *root;

  public:
    BinaryTree(int);
    void addNode(int);
    void inorder();
    void printInorder(node);
    int getHeight();
    int height(node);
};

BinaryTree::BinaryTree(int data){
    node *new = new node;
    new->data = data;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;

    root = new;
}

void BinaryTree::addNode(int data){
    node *new = new node;
    new->data = data;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;

    node *current;
    node *parent = NULL;
    current = root;

    while(current){
        parent = current;
        if(new->data > current->data) current = current->right;
        else current = current->left;
    }

    if(new->data < parent->data) parent->left = new;
    else parent->right = new;
}

void BinaryTree::inorder()
  printInorder(root);
}

void BinaryTree::printInorder(node current){
  if(current != NULL){
    if(tree->left) printInorder(tree->left);
    cout<<" "<<tree->data<<" ";
    if(tree->right) printInorder(tree->right);
  }
  else return;
}

int BinaryTree::getHeight(){
   return height(root);
}

int BinaryTree::height(node new){
  if (new == NULL) return 0;
  else return max(height(new->left), height(new->right)) + 1;
}


int main(int argCount, char *argVal[]){
  int number = atoi(argVal[1]);
  BinaryTree myTree = new BinaryTree(number);

  for(int i=2; i <= argCount; i++){
    number = atoi(argVal[i]);
    myTree.addNode(number);
  }

  myTree.inorder();
  int height = myTree.getHeight();
  cout << endl << "height = " << height << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is a C++ keyword. You mustn't use it as an identifier (e.g. variable name).

In any event, your constructor would be better off as:

```
BinaryTree::BinaryTree(int data) : root(new node) { /* ... */ }
```

And your class as a whole would probably be better off with `unique_ptr<Node>`s.

Answer (score 3):

new is keyword in c++ and You can't name variable with that word so

```
node *new = new node;
```

is illegal

Answer (score 3):

`new` is a [reserved word](http://programming.6forum.info/t17-c-reserved-words-reference-list), you cannot use it as a variable name.